# How to define expected return code in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have some scripts that ends with return codes different by zero and the task should be considered as success for the following tasks. Is there a way to configure which return codes the Airflow should consider as success in a DAG?

Comment: What type of Operator are you using?

Comment: I used BashOperator, WinRMOperator (with WinRMHook) and SSH_operator to execute a simple script that exits with return code 17 (local and remote execution). It makes the task fail.

What I'm trying to do is configure the expected code to accept the return code 0 and 17 as success and execute the next one.

Comment: I guess you need to handle the return code in the script - as far is know does any other return code than 0 let the task fail. However, you could still execute downstream tasks by changing the trigger rules.

Comment: Use `ssh host 'command' || true`